# AJAX Not Printing What PHP Returns?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am using ajax to print out a string received from my php file. The php file is creating rows for an html table. I am asking ajax to print these rows inside a  with a specific id that is inside of a  and i want it to print the rows when the page first loads up.
My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:'myphpfile.php',
    data: {action: 'name of function'},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result){
        $('#div1').html(result);
    }
});});
```

And I want it to print out the returned data here in my html:

```
<tbody>
    <div id='div1'>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

My PHP File basically does the following:

```
$htmlStr .= '<tr>';
$htmlStr .= '<td>Some Data</td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-center">' . some more data . '</td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-right">Rest of Data</td>';
$htmlStr .= '</tr>';
```

and I am returning that as follows:`echo json_encode($htmlStr);`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or why it is not printing out, I know it is using my php file because it returned errors in my php code before when I had bugs that I fixed, but now the bugs are fixed so there are no more errors, but the code still isn't being printed out. Please Help thank you!

Comment: you mean `$('#div1').html(result)`? `innerHTML` property has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, I had it changed in my code to see if it would do anything and forgot to chnage it back when I posted it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('#div1').html(result);` instead. By `$('#div1')` you are getting the element as jQuery object, that's why it was not working.

Also, if you've json encoded `htmlStr` you should store the html in an array and then encode it. Like:

```
<?php
    $response['html'] = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
    $response['success'] = true;
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Or you could just use plain html response without `json_encode` and removing the `dataType` from your ajax call.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this before, and it didn't work, I must have done something wrong when I did it though because it worked when I followed your steps, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @danglingCruze

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing javascript and jquery.

Change (in the ajax success)

```
$('#div1').innerHTML=result;
```

to

```
$('#div1').html(result);
```

Also you are appending `<tr>` ,so you cant have a `div` directly under `tbody`,so change the markup as something like.

```
$("tbody").html("<tr><div>"+your_result+"</div></tr>");
```

Also i guess you are JSON encoding in PHP so you can also do this,     `$('#div1').html(JSON.parse(result));`

Comment: that won't work because I have multiple tbody tags because I have multiple tables

Comment: @Aus10Zeh That was just a example,you can use some jquery to select each table seperatly

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `innerHTML`. Try changing it for `.html()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'myphpfile.php',
    data: {action: 'name of function'},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result){
         $('#div1').html(result);
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .html() and lose the json_encode, you are outputing a string, no need for encoding, just echo it

Comment: Yes, this worked, I had to change my string around a little, but it finally worked as I wanted it too, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dataType: "html"
```

and

```
$('#TableID > tbody').html( data );
```

and don't use json_encode just echo the html.

here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/6/